# How to ensure fragments aren't destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments and I want to make sure, none of them are destroyed as I swipe between them.

I'm trying to figure out the life cycle: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#lifecycle

And whether I need to put a "setRetainInstance" as soon as the fragment is put into onPause? And do I do it from the fragment or from my activity holding all my fragments or the PagerAdapter?

Here's my mainActivity.

```
package com.example.login3.YouPage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.login3.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private ImageView profilePic;
    private TextView profileName;
    private Button profileEdit;
    private Button logout;
    private Button updatePassword;
    private Button updateEmail;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //tabs
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.main_tabPager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    }


}
```

Here's my PagerAdapter

```
package com.example.login3.YouPage;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.login3.FeedFragment;
import com.example.login3.FriendsFragment;
import com.example.login3.NotifsFragment;
import com.example.login3.YouFragment;

class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new NotifsFragment();
            case 1:
                FeedFragment feedFregment = new FeedFragment();
                return feedFregment;
            case 2:
                FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                return friendsFragment;
            case 3:
                YouFragment youFragment = new YouFragment();
                return youFragment;

                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    //Titles on pages.
     public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "Notifs";
            case 1:
                return "Feed";
            case 2:
                return "Friends+";
            case 3:
                return "You";

            default:
                return null;
        }
    };

}
```

Or is there another more correct way to stop my fragments from being destroyed?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly on Viewpager with mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

setOffscreenPageLimit
added in version 22.1.0

void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: Is there a way to check/test if my fragments are being destroyed?

Comment: I guess you can add logs in onDestroy method in fragment and check if its getting called

Comment: Do I call it from each fragment or in my main?

Comment: You can call it from any fragment where you want to check will it be destroyed